# What is the output signal's frequency when doing operations of two signals?

Tags: sampling, convolution, frequency, nyquist

If I have two continuous time signals x(t) and y(t) of maximum frequencies Ω1, Ω2 respectively. I want to find the sampling frequency used used in continuous-discrete conversion of the following signals:
$$s(t) = x(t) + y(t)$$
$$d(t) = x(t) * y(t)$$
$$f(t) = x(t)  y(t)$$
I know that the sampling frequency is going to be twice the output frequency. However, I can't figure out what the frequency of the output is going to be. I know that if I have two added signals, I usually find the GCD of their periods to get the output signal's period. Is it the same in frequencies?

Comment: Is this homework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions can easily be solved using the [properties of the Fourier Transform](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Engineering_Tables/Fourier_Transform_Properties). Let capital letters denote the Fourier Transform of the time domain functions.

The Fourier Transform is a linear transform, thus, $S(f) = X(f) + Y(f)$. This means the highest frequency of $s(t)$ is max($\Omega1, \Omega2$).

The convolution of two signals corresponds to their product in the frequency domain, so $D(f) = X(f) Y(f)$. This will result in the highest frequency of $d(t)$ being min($\Omega1, \Omega2$).

Similarly, the product of two functions corresponds to their convolution in the frequency domain: $S(f) = X(f)*Y(f)$. Using the properties of convolution, the highest frequency of $s(t)$ is $\Omega1 + \Omega2$.